# Unity, character selection screen on same PC by two players

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

The game I am trying to make include local multiplayer to play on same PC. I have done by making the different controllers in input manager and game work perfectly fine.

But now I am onto the part where I have to create a character selection screen for multiple player on same PC. I am beginner to the unity and learning right now. So I have no idea how to make it happen. Because when I tried to make it unity UI didn't able to take two input. At a time

I have also watched some of the threads in which people suggested to make your own eventsystem and button but I tried doing that somehow buttons are not taking any response they are not clickable. If anyone has seen those thread and that method is working for them, so please let me know how to.make it work

Or if someone has any other idea how to do please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide code or screenshots of your current attempt?

Comment: Also can you elaborate on "unity UI didn't able to take two input. At a time" :)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you CAN'T have more than one event system in the same scene. 
So knowing that I'll suggest to change the...perspective about your game, here is something that can work:

You can't have more than one input on the same UI, but you can distinguish "keyboard" inputs. So let's guess the scenario that you have the screen divided in 2 parts, where left side is the Player 1 selection character, and can select between 2 characters, and right side is the Player 2 selection character, with the same number (or different, as you want!) of possible characters.

The pseudo code will be something like:

```
private Player m_player1;
private Player m_player2;

private CharacterSelection m_CharacterSelection_Player1;
private CharacterSelection m_CharacterSelection_Player2;

If (m_Player1.Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
  m_CharacterSelection_Player1.Left();
}
else if(m_Player1.Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)){
  m_CharacterSelection_Player1.Right();
}

If (m_Player2.Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
  m_CharacterSelection_Player2.Left();
}
else if(m_Player1.Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
  m_CharacterSelection_Player2.Right();
}
```

Here is the visual representation about what I'm trying to tell you:
[image]